# Pandas EmptyDataError In File that contains data

Tags: python, pandas

While I was programing something to read in a huge collection of text files and parse them into a single dataframe, I came across an EmptyDataError for one of my files. It stated that that file contained no columns of data to parse, but when I had a closer look at the file that wasn't true at all. It was populated with data in columns.  I had a look at the delimiters as well to confirm that the delimiters weren't an issue and they stayed consistent with the delimiters I'd used. How do I go about solving this?

Code:

```
column_names = ["Left_Mean", "Left_SD", "Left_Skew", "Left_Kurt", "Right_Mean", "Right_SD", "Right_Skew", "Right_Kurt", 'Mean_Dif']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
holds_data = []
latency_data = []
holds = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

for user in users:
  filenames = glob.glob('/content/RSI_Keylogger/Shared drives/RSI_Keylogger/data/Tappy_Data/{}*.txt'.format(user))
  if "/content/RSI_Keylogger/Shared drives/RSI_Keylogger/data/Archived_users/User_"+user+".txt" in userrs:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
          outfile.write(infile.read())
          try:
            df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/output_file.txt', header=None, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0,3,4,5,6])
            df1 = df1.append(df2)
          except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
            print(filenames)
            raise
      if len(df1) > 1999:

        holdl = pd.to_numeric(df1[df1[3] == 'L'][4], errors='coerce')
        holdl = holdl.dropna()

        LM = holdl.mean()
        LSD = holdl.std()
        LSK = scipy.stats.skew(holdl)
        LK = scipy.stats.kurtosis(holdl)

        holdr = pd.to_numeric(df1[df1[3] == 'R'][4], errors='coerce')
        holdr = holdr.dropna()

        RM = holdr.mean()
        RSD = holdr.std()
        RSK = scipy.stats.skew(holdr)
        RK = scipy.stats.kurtosis(holdr)

        MD_1 = abs(LM - RM)

        holds_data = [LM, LSD, LSK, LK, RM, RSD, RSK, RK, MD_1]

        df = df.append(holds_data)
        holds = holds.append(df)
```

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7aAb.png)

Comment: Can you show the sample of your data?

Comment: Yeah @LazyCoder, I just added a link to it.

Comment: Can you also provide your method of importing?

Comment: @LazyCoder I just appended my code. Don't expect anything too great from it haha.

Comment: Can you try using `delim_whitespace=True` instead of `delimiter='\t'`.  Sometimes when tabs are expanded `delimiter='\t'` might fail

Comment: @LazyCoder Hi, I'm still experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.errors.EmptyDataError.html, your file is really empty.

I'd seriously doubt that is not what's happening.

I don't know your code, but to debug I'd add a print and possibly an assert of the file before opening with pandas:

```
for filepath in filepaths:
    filesize = length(open(filepath).read())
    print("File {} has length {}.".format(filepath, filesize))
    # you can even assert that:
    assert filesize > 0, "Error! File is empty!"

    datafrmae = pd.read_csv(filepath, ...)  # now we know it's not empty
```

---

## UPDATED with access with your code

The problem seems to be

```
    with open(fname) as infile:
      outfile.write(infile.read())
      try:
        df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/output_file.txt', header=None, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0,3,4,5,6])
        df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

You are reading to df2, the output file itself, which you are writing to, instead of `pd.read_csv(fname, ...)`. Thus it will crash instantly especially if the output file starts empty. Also, there are no flushes, hence, as `outfile` was not closed or flushed, it might be empty when you read it.

Anyway, I think a bigger problem is I don't understand what you really want to do but it seems very convoluted. I'd advise against reading the file you're writing to, that seems wrong.

And since you have df1 already, why not write that to disk at the end? Pandas will be efficient, no need for so many file opens and reads and writes, use pandas. Read each file to df2, append it to df1, and use df1, and if you want, write df1 to disk with `df1.to_csv`.

Comment: Hi there, I ran your code to debug it and I found that the file really did have data. Using your code to debug it and the len method, I retrieved a length of 522 in the problematic file which remained consistent with its size of 522 bytes. In my original code, I ran a try/except block to catch the file and the file that was returned was the same file that gave me a length of 522. I'll paste my code here so that you could have a better look.